# Android get specific Json data from url to variables

Tags: android, html, json

I am newbie in Android programing and i tring to save from json that i have from url. Its a different type of json, thats why i cant get long with it.

```
 [  

   {  
      "vartype":"value",
      "varid":"rebooting",
      "varvalue":"0"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"value",
      "varid":"provis_inet",
      "varvalue":"xx3"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"value",
      "varid":"provis_voip",
      "varvalue":"xx0"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"value",
      "varid":"save_fails",
      "varvalue":"0"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"status",
      "varid":"loginstate",
      "varvalue":"1"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"status",
      "varid":"status",
      "varvalue":"ok"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"option",
      "varid":"askAssist",
      "varvalue":"0"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"option",
      "varid":"dontstartAssist",
      "varvalue":"0"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"option",
      "varid":"internetFinished",
      "varvalue":"1"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"option",
      "varid":"use_telephone",
      "varvalue":"0"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"option",
      "varid":"wlanFinished",
      "varvalue":"0"
   },
   {  
      "vartype":"status",
      "varid":"login",
      "varvalue":"success"
   }
]
```

My problem is it that there is vartype, varid and varvalue, but i need the varid value and the varvalue value like : "login"="success"
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON Objects are contained within an array which is very common. I suggest using Retrofit client to handle JSON within your app. Documentation for it can be found [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/). You will need to create models that are structured in a hierarchy just like the JSON. Use this [site](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org) to quickly create it. I hope this helps you get started and like I said, there's plenty of documentation and tutorials out there to accomplish what you are doing, just a Google search away. If you have any additional, specific, questions feel free to ask away on here and I'll help out. If I answered your question correctly please mark it as such so others can benefit.

Comment: I give a look on it, seems a bit hard to me :(

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response_json)

 for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
{
     JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    //and get value for array
    String varvalue= jsonObject.getString("varvalue").toString()
}
```

I hope help this

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work :( or i did something bad

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4b9fzmRyGwwTmhMVU9mTFRiUFE/view?usp=sharing

the main activity of my code, the other things are work but it isn't surelly i do something bad, if you could look at it, it would be good @Rathod Vijay

Comment: You can check this tutorial same as your json format example 
http://www.tricksofit.com/2013/12/android-json-parsing-from-url#.Vte3Q_l96M8

Comment: You can change this line

//String varvalue= jsonObject.getString("varvalue").toString()


JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            //and get value for array
                            String varvalue= jsonObject.getString("varvalue").toString();

Comment: I tried it and not working :( i tried to make it string, and after that search in that it works for now